# How to monitor a Magento Upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I'm wondering if there is a way to monitor the progress of a Magento upgrade?

I see that entries are written to `var/log/update.log` from time to time, but during an web-base **upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.1.6**

I find that I am not getting any feedback for many minutes at a time.

(could be as much as 60 min) Not sure of the exact time because the log entries don't match the system time.

In fact the time stamps appear to be within 2 minutes of each other.

Is there anything else I can check to monitor the progress of the upgrade?

Comment: Have you run show processlist in Mysql? That will show you what the site is doing in the db

Answer (score 1):

Since nearly everything you are waiting for is database updates you should review processlist.

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
|  2 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | init  | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

You can also use Blackfire and NewRelic